# bug where the border of the table is not visible

Tags: css, html-table, border

i don't understand why border of first tbody tr's td is not visible.

[image]
i think there is no reason border is not visible.

what i fugure out is this.

1. if natural height of th is higher than height i fixed for th, first tbody tr's td is visible.
2. if there is no code th{height: xxpx; }, first tbody tr's td is visible.

```css
.table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table.summary-style
{
    font-size: 11px;

    width: 100%;

    table-layout: fixed;

    text-align: center;

    color: #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    background: #fff;
}

.table.summary-style caption
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
    /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    opacity: 0;
}

.table.summary-style thead th
{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;

    position: relative;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 5px 4px;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    color: #666;
    background: #ddd;
}

.table.summary-style > tbody > tr > td
{
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.38;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 4px 10px;

    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;

    color: #666;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="table summary-style">
         
         
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">No Data.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The border is visible? If you mean there is no border on the side, swap border-top:` with just `border:`

Comment: maybe i can change the way you suggest. but i don't still why browser don't render border. i want to know why. is it just bug?. i can't find ariticle about bug like acting this.

Comment: It's not a bug. By writing `  border-top` , you have specified you only want the border to show on the `top`

Comment: i already wirte border-top to tbody's td.

Comment: i think border top of td of tbody's first tr should be visible even i don't change code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `position: relative;` on `.table.summary-style thead th` causes that row of elements to appear 'above' the borders of other elements. This is despite the fact that `box-sizing: border-box;` has been used, as the borders of the table elements have been collapsed together. The solution is to either remove `position: relative;` on the first row or remove `border-collapse: collapse;` from `.table`.

```css
.table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table.summary-style
{
    font-size: 11px;

    width: 100%;

    table-layout: fixed;

    text-align: center;

    color: #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    background: #fff;
}

.table.summary-style caption
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
    /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    opacity: 0;
}

.table.summary-style thead th
{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 5px 4px;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    color: #666;
    background: #ddd;
}

.table.summary-style > tbody > tr > td
{
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.38;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 4px 10px;

    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;

    color: #666;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="table summary-style">
         
         
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">No Data.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand exctly why it happen!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.table.summary-style {
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  background: #fff;
}

.table.summary-style caption {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.table.summary-style thead th {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 5px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #666;
  background: #ddd;
}

.table.summary-style>tbody>tr>td {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.38;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #666;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="table summary-style">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">No Data.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```